# Is this one-hot encoding?

Tags: python, machine-learning, scikit-learn, one-hot-encoding

Reading :

http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.preprocessing.LabelEncoder.html

it states "encode categorical integer features using a one-hot aka one-of-K scheme."

Does this also mean it one-hot encodes a list of words ?

From Wikipedia definition ( https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/One-hot ) of one hot encoding
"In natural language processing, a one-hot vector is a 1 × N matrix (vector) used to distinguish each word in a vocabulary from every other word in the vocabulary. The vector consists of 0s in all cells with the exception of a single 1 in a cell used uniquely to identify the word."

Running code below it appears `LabelEncoder` is not a correct implementation of one hot encoding whereas `OneHotEncoder` is a correct implementation :

```
import numpy as np
from sklearn.preprocessing import MultiLabelBinarizer
from numpy import array
from numpy import argmax
from sklearn.preprocessing import LabelEncoder
from sklearn.preprocessing import OneHotEncoder

# define example
data = ['w1 w2 w3', 'w1 w2']

values = array(data)
label_encoder = LabelEncoder()
integer_encoded = label_encoder.fit_transform(values)

# binary encode
onehot_encoder = OneHotEncoder(sparse=False)
integer_encoded = integer_encoded.reshape(len(integer_encoded), 1)

mlb = MultiLabelBinarizer()

print('fit_transform\n' , mlb.fit_transform(data))
print('\none hot\n' , onehot_encoder.fit_transform(integer_encoded))
```

Prints :

```
fit_transform
 [[1 1 1 1 1]
 [1 1 1 0 1]]

one hot
 [[0. 1.]
 [1. 0.]]
```

So `LabelEncoder` does not one-hot encode , what is the type of encoding used by `LabelEncoder`  ?

From above outputs it appears `OneHotEncoder` produces a more dense vector than encoding scheme of `LabelEncoder`.

Update :

How to decide to encode data for machine learning algorithms using LabelEncoder or OneHotEncoder ?

Comment: Categorical != one hot. Categorical => mapping values from one domain to another. One hot => K-length vector with only one element activated.

Comment: pandas also has a command [get_dummies()](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.get_dummies.html?highlight=get_dummies) which may be useful.

Comment: LabelEncoder produces a Ordinal encoding. Also the documentation of "encode categorical integer features using a one-hot aka one-of-K scheme" in LabelEncoder is for the description of OneHotEncoder in the see-also section, and does not apply to LabelEncoder.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think your question is not clear enough...

First, `LabelEncoder` encodes labels with value between `0` and `n_classes-1` while `OneHotEncoder` encodes categorical integer features using a one-hot aka one-of-K scheme. They are different.

Second, yes `OneHotEncoder` encodes a list of words. In Wikipedia definition, it says `a one-hot vector is a 1 × N matrix`. But what is `N`? Actually, `N` is the size of your vocabulary.

For example, if you have five words `a, b, c, d, e`. Then one-hot-encode them:

```
a -> [1, 0, 0, 0, 0]  # a one-hot 1 x 5 vector
b -> [0, 1, 0, 0, 0]  # a one-hot 1 x 5 vector
c -> [0, 0, 1, 0, 0]  # a one-hot 1 x 5 vector
d -> [0, 0, 0, 1, 0]  # a one-hot 1 x 5 vector
e -> [0, 0, 0, 0, 1]  # a one-hot 1 x 5 vector
# total five one-hot 1 x 5 vectors which can be expressed in a 5 x 5 matrix.
```

Third, actually I'm not 100% sure what you are asking...

Finally, to answer your updated question. Most of time you should choose one-hot encoding or [word embedding](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Word_embedding). The reason is, the vectors generated by `LabelEncoder` are too similar which means there isn't much difference between each other. As the similar input are more likely to result similar output. That makes your model difficult to fit.